# Select limited and ordered records from first table matching with second table

Tags: mysql, limit, multiple-tables

I have two tables: **threads** and **comments**

Threads:

- id
- author_id

Comments:

- thread_id
- author_id

**thread_id** in **Commets** table is linked to **id** in **Threads** table.

Initially i have **author_id** of user, that posted some Comments in several Threads.

I want to select records from Threads, where my user posted Comments.
These records should be limited and ordered by **id**.
And my user **should not** be author of Threads.

Please, help. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use only a single table, answer me???

Comment: Actually i have absolutely different tables and they are can not be in single table. "Threads" and "Comments" i used to simplify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SET @author_id=1;
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Threads
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL 
    FROM Comments
    WHERE author_id=@author_id
    AND Threads.thread_id = Comments.id
)
AND NOT author_id=@author_id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you! I got, that i want from your answer. But answer is not fully correct.

Comment: SELECT * FROM threads WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM comments WHERE author_id = '$user_id' AND threads.id = comments.thread_id) AND author_id != '$user_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10